# Moongose 3.6.11, key "options" in a model

Tags: javascript, mongoose

i just migrate to mongoose 3.6.11
One of my model have a key named "options" in it's schema, but now i have problem with it

So how can i rename it without loss data (i have plenty of row to modify) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

yeah, i answer myself, so here is the operator $rename of mongodb
[mongodb $rename](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/rename/)